# Regarding Rayleigh-Sommerfeld Diffraction Integral

Tags: mathematical-physics, integration, diffraction, special-functions

While studying the Rayleigh-Sommerfeld diffraction formula I get the standard result for the following  integration given at *serial no. 11 under section 8.421 of "Table of Integrals" by Gradshteyn and Ryjhik* :

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\exp ik[\sqrt{s^2+x^2}]}{\sqrt{s^2+x^2}}\,dx=i\pi H_0^1 (ks)$$
Now my question is as follows:

**1)** In my calculation involving circular geometry, it appears that

$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\,d\phi\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp i[k r\sin \phi]\times \frac{\exp -ia_0\sqrt{[s^2+r^2+\beta^2+2r\beta \sin \phi]}}{\sqrt{[s^2+r^2+\beta^2+2r\beta \sin \phi]}}r\,dr$$

Where, $i^2=-1$; $k$, $\beta$ and $a_0$ are constants. Further, $s<<r$ and $r dr d\phi$ represents the area of the circular aperture. 
The first part i.e. $\exp i[k r\sin \phi]$ can be represented as a Bessel function but the remaining part also contains $r \sin \phi$ in its argument, so, I could not do the mixed integral.

Would you kindly suggest me how I can get the closed-form answer of the integral (2) from the given result or is there any other way such that this integral can be converted to a standard integral of bessel/ hankel function given in *"Table of Integrals" by Gradshyteyn and Ryjhik*. 
Thanking you..

Comment: Just to let you know, $i \neq \sqrt{-1}$, it's defined as being such that $i^2 =-1$ which is not the same thing as there are two solutions. Said another way, $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}[x] /(x^2+1)$.

Comment: Ok. thanks... it is changed accordingly.But would you kindly throw any light on the process of finding closed form solution...